# Select hasMany association cakephp3 not working?

Tags: php, cakephp

i have 2 table 
users and user_stories
users hasMany user_stories

**users struct**

`id | name`

**user_stories**

`id | user_id | story_name`

at **UsersTable**
`$this->hasMany('UserStories')->setForeignKey('user_id ');`

at **UserStories**
`$this->belongsTo('Users')->setForeignKey('user_id');`

```
$query = $this->find();
$query->contain([
    'UserStories'
])->select([
    'UserStories.name'
]);
```

Error unknown column `UserStories.name`

Comment: There is no field with `name` in `user_stories`. If you want to get name from the users table then use `Users.name`. If you want story_name then you have to select `UserStories.story_name`

Comment: `UserStories.story_name` i mean that :D so still select at hasMany  association cake3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select fields in contain section

```
$query = $this->find();
$query->contain([
    'UserStories' [
        'fields' => [
            'UserStories.name'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

More info check [Eager Loading Associations Via Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain)

Comment: how about select `name` at users

Comment: Add `->select([
    'Users.name'
])`